# saving and loading blotter portfolio

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

I am using blotter to hold and do the accounting of some transactions, but I would need to save and load them on a daily basis.

I haven´t been able to save my transactions, I believe that that happens because they are in a different enviroment created by blotter (.blotter) - from what I´ve been able to pick up by googling my questions.

I have set up an example of a transaction:

```
require(quantstrat)
currency("USD")
stock(primary_id = "SB1", currency = "USD", multiplier=1120, tick_size = 0.01)
initPortf(name="testport", symbols="SB1", initDate = "2017-11-01")
initAcct(name="testacct", portfolio="testport", initDate = "2017-11-01", initEq = 100000)
ls_instruments()
addTxn(Portfolio="testport", Symbol="SB1", TxnDate="2017-11-22", TxnPrice=15.00, TxnQty = 2 , verbose=TRUE)
getPos(Portfolio="testport", Symbol="SB1", "2017-11-22", Columns=c("Pos.Qty"))
```

Then I try to save it (which didn´t work) and was thinking about loading it like in the code below:

```
save("testport", file="C:/Users/augus/Dropbox/Trading/R/Trading/Dados/test.RData", envir=.blotter)
load(file="C:/Users/augus/Dropbox/Trading/R/Trading/Dados/test.RData", verbose=TRUE)
```

I am pretty knew to R and stackoverflow, so please let me know if I am missing any information in my question, and thanks a lot for the help.

All the best,

Augusto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you wanted was actually "portfolio.testport", not "testport" (this is designed this way in blotter).  You can check by looking at what is in the `.blotter` environment:

```
ls(.blotter)
#[1] "account.testacct"   "portfolio.testport"
```

You could do this instead:

```
save("portfolio.testport", file="test.RData", envir=.blotter)
save("testport", file="C:/Users/augus/Dropbox/Trading/R/Trading/Dados/test.RData", envir=.blotter)
load(file="test.RData", verbose=TRUE)
```

You may not want to store all of the stuff in this portfolio though, so it helps to understand what makes up the portfolio.

```
p <- getPortfolio("testport")
class(p)
#[1] "blotter_portfolio" "portfolio"
```

It is basically a list, containing a summary (xts) and a symbols object (another list):

```
ls(p)
#[1] "summary" "symbols"
```

The contents of the symbols list is:

```
ls(p$symbols)
#[1] "SB1"
```

And each symbol object is also a list, containing 3 xts objects:

```
ls(p$symbols$SB1)
#[1] "posPL"     "posPL.USD" "txn"
```

`txn` is one of the objects (an xts object itself):

```
head(p$symbols$SB1$txn)
# Txn.Qty Txn.Price Txn.Value Txn.Avg.Cost Pos.Qty Pos.Avg.Cost Gross.Txn.Realized.PL Txn.Fees Net.Txn.Realized.PL Con.Mult
# 2017-11-01       0         0         0            0       0            0                     0        0                   0        0
# 2017-11-22       2        15     33600           15       2           15                     0        0                   0     1120
```

You may wish to save only sub parts of the above portfolio object.

Here is another approach you might find useful for saving:

```
p <- getPortfolio("testport")
saveRDS(p, "test2.rds")
p <- readRDS("test2.rds")
```